# how to implement __getitem__ and __getattr__ simultaneously?

Tags: python-3.x

Suppose I have a class where the data is stored in multiple attributes, but the user of the class sees only one data. For example:

```
class TestClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
        self.b = [-4, -3, -2, -1]

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return [(self.a[elem] if elem < len(self.a) else self.b[elem - len(self.a)]) 
                for elem in item]
```

then, I can define:

```
In[]: x = TestClass()
Out[]: x[(1,3,5,6)]
[2, 4, -3, -2]
```

Now, it would be quite nice to add some functionality to this such as

```
           x[(1,3,5,6)].mean()           (or some other function)
```

One way could be to redefine a new class TestClassSuper

```
class TestClassSuper:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def mean(self):
        return mean(self.value)
```

and then modify the `__getitem__` function within `TestClass` to return

```
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return TestClassSuper([(self.a[elem] if elem < len(self.a) 
                                             else self.b[elem - len(self.a)]) 
                                for elem in item])
```

But, I was wondering if there is an alternative way to define `__getattr__` that can handle a call like `x[(1,3,5,6)].mean()` within `TestClass` itself instead of defining a `TestClassSuper` wrapper?

I am using Python 3.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The item access is performed first, and then the attribute lookup is performed on the result. There is no way to merge the two into a single operation.